# In Delphi is there a way to see all references and links to a component?

Tags: delphi

I'm refactoring a large project and have the need to move some components to new modules and forms.  Is there a sane way to make sure properties of dependent components are updated?

Maybe grep the project's dfms?

Example:  Moving a TDataSource from a huge DataModule to a smaller one.  In some cases the source could have been references by 40-50 forms.  I need to make sure all controls that reference the data source get updated.

Comment: I'd grep the dfm files and then I'd use a perl regex based script to make the necessary modifications

Comment: Later versions of Delphi allow you to refactor and rename from the editor. Have you tried that feature? Also, it's a good idea to remove it completely from the original location or rename it so your compiler will catch what you miss.

Comment: @marcus rename refactoring never works with real world projects. I'd be astounded if it handled dfm file references.

Comment: I'd try Icaraus from Peganza.  It's a pascal analyzer. Not 100% sure it will do this, but I would give it a shot.  http://www.peganza.com/products_icarus.htm

Comment: "Icarus" is only for analyzing uses clauses - the complete tool is named "Pascal Analyzer". I'm not sure it will help in this case.

Comment: @David: Where are you seeing porblems?  I use Rename Refactoring a lot and rarely have it mess up on me.  When it does, a restart of the IDE seems to clean it up, suggesting some continued IDE stability issues.

Comment: @Bruce Perhaps it doesn't like my code. But it works fine for very local changes and never manages a rename that spans more than 2 or 3 files. It never does anything wrong, it just fails to find all the references. If the *real* compiler was used rather than one of the fake compilers then I'm sure all would be well.

Comment: @David; You're not alone, lots of things work fine in demo projects that don't work very well in complex real world applications, especially where newer Delphi syntax gets in the way of some of the parsers inside Delphi working completely as they ought to.

Comment: @marcus removing it won't generate compiler errors. All that happens is the reference is removed in any dependent components. If you remove a TDataSource from where it was referenced by a data aware component, the IDE empties the DataSource property on the components that referenced it. You're stuck tracking things down at run-time which can be a real pain.

Comment: I have been using Rename Refactoring on production code recently, including changing the names of components used across units.  I will try some more to see if I can make it mess up.  Thanks goodness for source control.  :)

Comment: @David, I agree that having separate parsers is a problem.  If that were resolved, then my favourite glitch (phantom squigglies) would probably go away, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GREP in [GEXperts](http://www.gexperts.org/) allows to search both pas and dfm files.

Comment: This was the quickest way for me to achieve exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if ModelMaker CodeExplorer had some pretty powerful capabilities in this area too.

Answer (score 5):

First, I sure hope you're using version control.

I realize this is a "so obvious" answer, but the best way I've found to see all references and links to a component is (using version control so I can revert all changes later), rename the property or component, and then see what breaks.

Pascal Analyzer is not much help here.

The Refactoring features of Delphi might be helpful (try a rename refactoring, and see how many places it can suggest that it would automatically rename for you). Do not apply the change, simply review the suggestions.

As far as "moving rather than renaming" some control or resource, ask "why" you are doing it. Why move the datasource?  A datasource is simply a landing point for your data aware controls, and you are allowed to have more than one datasource pointing to a single dataset. Why not move only the datasets, and leave the datasources where they are?

Comment: Datasources included in a MEGADATAMODULE that is now being split up and sources put on the forms that need them.

Comment: In Pascal Analyzer, "Brief Cross-reference" shows where all identifiers are used.

Comment: @Bruce, I cannot make Pascal Analyzer find rerefences in DFM files. If it works for you, what are your settings?

Comment: +1 for version control. If things go wrong, you can always revert to a stable version. It will save you hours of headache when messing around with TDataSource and data ware components.

Comment: @Warren, It's easy to miss thi8ngs like this in Pascal Analyzer.  I remembered seeing it but had to go looking.

Comment: The "see what brakes" part is a bit problematic. To be sure, you would have to open every single form, check every single function in your project, at runtime. I'm fairly certain even for a systematic approach this is extremely impractical, assuming a larger than 2 forms project.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using XE or later, you can right-click on a component name or other identifier in the code editor and select [Search for Usages](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Searching_Source_Code_for_Usages) to get the list of references to update.

Update:
Unfortunately, this only works for source code references and doesn't show where an identifier is used in the DFM.

Comment: I'm not seeing this work on the dfm level.  I need to find the drop down list I just killed by renaming or moving it's lookup table.  In my experience these instances can not be found via syntax check nor does Search for Usages go into dfms.

Comment: Does it find usages in DFM files? I tried a TImageList in a datamodule which is connected to a menu and a toolbar in two different frames - none of the frames was found.

Comment: @Uwe, Sadly, no.  Like Pascal Analyzer, it only works for source code references.

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi or Notepad++, do a Find In Files for MEGADATAMODULE, and be sure to include your entire source branch. That should find all instances.  You can also, using Notepad++, do the search on all .dcp, .bpl, .dll, and .exe binaries, to see what should probably be re-built.

Comment: AFAIK, "Find in Files" in Delphi does not find references in DFM files.

Comment: it does, if, instead of "search in all files in project group", you use "search in directories", and use proper file mask.